# Ember.js: How to represent a has-many model relationship?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, relationship

I am trying to set up an ember app where I have many Items, all of which have many Options.  I then need a 'dashboard' area where I can monitor information on all Items/Options.

In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056283/ember-js-how-to-use-an-arraycontroller-to-describe-multiple-models/20057022?noredirect=1#20057022) I got a working example of a dashboard which monitors a single collection of Items.
**How do I update this to represent child Options for each Item?**

**Javascript** - [from jsBin (updated)](http://jsbin.com/IgoJiWi/20/edit?html,js,output)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

/* ROUTES */
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('items');
  this.resource('dashboard');
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('items');
  }
});
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var a = Em.A();
    a.pushObject( App.Items.create({title: 'A', cost: '100'}));
    a.pushObject( App.Items.create({title: 'B', cost: '200'}));
    a.pushObject( App.Items.create({title: 'C', cost: '300'}));
    return a;
  }
});

/* MODELS */
App.Items = Ember.Object.extend({
  title: '',
  cost: '',
  quantity: ''
});


/* CONTROLLERS */
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  legend: 'test',
  len: function(){
    return this.get('length');
  }.property('length'),
  totalCost: function() {
    return this.reduce( function(prevCost, cost){
      return parseInt(cost.get('cost'),10) + (prevCost || 0);
    });
  }.property('@each.cost')
});
App.DashboardController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['items'],
  itemsLength: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.items.len'),
  itemsTotalCost: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.items.totalCost')  
});
```

**Handlebars**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <p><strong>Ember.js example</strong><br>Using an a dashboard that monitors 'items'.</p>
    {{render dashboard}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    <h2>Items:</h2>
    <dl>
      {{#each}}
        <dt>Title: {{title}}</dt>
        <dd>Cost: {{cost}} {{input value=cost}}</dd>
      {{/each}}
    </dl>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
    <h2>Overview:</h2>
    {{#if controllers.items}}
    <p>Total number of items (expect 3): {{itemsLength}}<br>
    Total cost of items (expect 600): {{itemsTotalCost}}</p>
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upfront, I would recommend using a clientside record management framework like ember data/ember model, they are a bit of a learning curve, but very awesome in the long run.  If you don't want to do that, you can follow the same pattern you've already established with creating models.

http://jsbin.com/IpEfOwA/3/edit

Comment: I am having trouble getting the dashboard to monitor the options the same way it monitors the items.  It looks like `controllers.options` doesn't exist - why would that be?  http://jsbin.com/ugoTAguB/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Because you've never created anything that uses the options controller.  What are you trying to accomplish in the dashboard?  a count of all of the options inside of all of the items?  grab the items from the items controller, and iterate over them counting the options.

Comment: The dashboard will need all the data from Items & Options so it can do various calculations.  Importantly, it also needs to be updated when certain Item/Option properties change.  

I think that accessing the Options via the Items does not allow the Dashboard to observe Option changes.  Is that true? http://jsbin.com/IyamobAf/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Sure, just add a computed property at the item level that watches the options, and at the item controller level that watches the items http://jsbin.com/eZuzoCAT/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a ton for all your help; I think this is the starting point that I need.

Comment: Np, it takes a bit to get some of the basics down, but once you get a few of them, it becomes super powerful.

Comment: The 'options' template in your jsbin uses `{{#each option in controller }}` but I don't see controller defined anywhere.  Is this an Ember convention to access the template's controller?

Comment: If you don't define an item controller it just iterates over the items from the model (it proxies down from the controller)