# Ember.js: ArrayController undefined in template

Tags: ember.js

**Problem:**

I am kind of struggling with the organization of my first ember app. The current issue is that the my `Items` ArrayController is not defined in my `dashboard` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
    {{#if controllers.items}}
        <p class="alert alert-error">Dashboard can access item's info - Nice!</p>
    {{else}}
        <p class="alert alert-error">Dashboard cannot access items... :-/</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

**Likely cause:** *

**EDIT: after talking with @conrad below, I'm kind of questioning this:*

I had a similar issue in an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078113/ember-js-how-to-represent-a-has-many-model-relationship/20078430?noredirect=1#comment29953574_20078430) and kingpin2k suggested the cause was that I:

> "never created anything that uses the options controller".

This is probably the case here as well.  [This quick screencast](http://screencast.com/t/3ZsQLhorba) shows that a breakpoint on my ArrayController is not hit on page load - but it ***is*** hit when I inspect the Items controller in the Ember inspector tool (eg, Ember creates the ArrayController object right then for the first time).

**Apparent non-solutions:**

My `Dashboard` controller says it needs the `Items` controller.  I guess that isn't enough to instantiate the ArrayController?

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  len: function(){
    return this.get('length');
  }.property('length'),

  totalCost: function() {
    return this.reduce( function(prevCost, item){
      return parseInt(item.get('values').findBy('type', 'cost').price, 10) + prevCost;
    }, 0);
  }.property('@each.values')

  [more computed properties...]

});

App.DashboardController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['items'],
  itemsLength: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.items.len'),
  itemsTotalCost: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.items.totalCost'),

  [more computed properties...]
});
```

Furthermore, each item in `Items` ***is*** being rendered in my `items` template.  I guess that does not create the missing `controllers.items` either...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    {{#each}}
        [these render fine]
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="display">
<!-- DISPLAY TEMPLATE -->

    {{!- DASHBOARD -}}
    {{render dashboard}}

    {{!- ITEMS -}}
    {{render 'items' items}}

</script>
```

**So then.. what?**

I can imagine many possible avenues, but haven't gotten any of them to work yet:

- Specify the Items ArrayController in `{{render dashboard}}`?
- Some configuration in a Route?
- Maybe my templates/routes are not correctly arranged?

[image: Ember view tree]
[image: Ember routes]

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the `ItemController` is instantiated in the dashboard template by calling it in the `DashboardController`'s init function:

```
App.DashboardController = Em.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['items'],
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.get('controllers.items.length');
    }
});
```

/edit:

removed the part that was not helpful

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm getting an error saying that `this` has no method 'super'.  Inspecting 'this' item, all I see is a '_super' function.  When I call that function instead, I'm still not able to access 'controllers.items' from the template.

Comment: Alternatively, you could call for {{itemsLength}} in your dashboard template which should invoke and instantiate the itemsController. After that, {{#if controllers.items}} should evaluate to true.

Comment: I implemented both of your suggestions.  1) Adding {{itemsLength}} does not make {{#if controllers.items}} eval to true.  2) {{itemsLength}} evals to zero. 3) `this.get('controllers.items.length');` from above returns 0 and other properties are 'undefined'.  Now I'm second guessing my suspected problem..

Comment: Hmm could it be that you never assign the items to the ItemController? That would explain why itemLength is 0. I don't know the rest of your code, do you, in the `DashboardRoute`, call `this.controllerFor('items').set('model', items)` or similar?

Comment: That is possible (I don't explicitly add Items to the ItemController). I've been assuming that 1) ember figures out the association between Item objs & my Items ArrayController and, 2) the fact that [Items looks correct in the inspector](http://screencast.com/t/DFRAxEzn7Bh) means that that isn't the problem.  What is the proper way to populate an ArrayController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41721/discussion-between-conrad-friedrich-and-doub1ejack)